# How do I use Linux commands in my C programs

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm a beginner on Ubuntu and I encounter some difficulties while coding.

What library do I include to use Linux commands in my C programs? And which function do I use to execute these commands?

for example, we include "windows.h" when coding on Windows and we use `system("command")` to call some command.

I want to know how I could do such things while coding on Ubuntu.

Comment: `system` is a function in the C standard library. You can use that on Ubuntu as well

Comment: If you include stdlib.h and then call system, it should work, since it's in the standard library.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks you!